# PHP cURL request is showing loading screen

Tags: php, web-scraping, php-curl

I am trying to scrape this website https://www.virustotal.com/#/ip-address/50.116.24.15 using PHP cURL. But i get no data.I just see a loading screen. How to bypass this loading screen?
Here is my code:

```js
<?php 

 $url = 'https://www.virustotal.com/#/ip-address/50.116.24.15';
 $htm = getCurlData($url);
 echo $htm;

function getCurlData($url)
{
     $ch = curl_init($url);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
     $contents = curl_exec($ch);
     curl_close($ch);
     return $contents;
}

 ?>
```

Comment: This might not work: to me, it looks like a AJAX request, as the part after the `#` sign is never sent to the server. Additionally, I don't think that scraping that site is allowed - why don't you use their API?

Comment: Thanks...I am trying to use their API now...